# Suppose that $f$ is integrable and for each Borel $A$ there is an $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $c$ such that $\int_A|f(A)| \leq c m(A)^{\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Suppose that $f$ is integrable and for each Borel $A$ there is an $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $c$ such that $\int_A|f| \leq c m(A)^{\alpha}$, with $m$ Lebesgue measure. Then $f \in L^p(\Bbb R)$ for some $p > 1$.

The converse of this theorem is an easy application of Holder's inequality, so I tried to show that $f \in L^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}$, but can't seem to get anywhere. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: You don't want $f(A)$ there. Don't you want to say there exist $\alpha, c$ such that for each Borel ...

Comment: They do not. And that you for catching that.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $c$ should be independent of $A$, right? The first sentence makes it appear as if we can pick $\alpha$ and $c$ after $A$ has been fixed, but then this wouldn't be much of a condition.

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes they are, sorry for not making this more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed $p>1$ (to be specified later), start by writing
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^p=\int_{|f|\leq 1}|f|^p+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{2^{k-1}<|f|\leq 2^k}|f|^p\leq \int_{|f|\leq 1}|f|+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{k(p-1)}\int_{2^{k-1}<|f|\leq 2^k}|f| $$
Then applying the given condition to $A=\{2^{k-1}<|f|\leq 2^k\}$, we get
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^p\leq ||f||_1+c\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{k(p-1)}m(2^{k-1}<|f|\leq 2^k)^{\alpha} $$
Next, we have
$$ m(2^{k-1}<|f|\leq 2^k)\leq m(|f|>2^{k-1})\leq \frac{||f||_1}{2^{k-1}}=\frac{2||f||_1}{2^k} $$
by Chebyshev's inequality, hence
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^p\leq||f||_1+c2^{\alpha}||f||_1^{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{k(p-1-\alpha)}$$

The sum will be finite as long as $p-1-\alpha<0$, i.e. $p<1+\alpha$, and since $\alpha>0$ we can choose $p>1$ satisfying this condition.

Comment: Thank you, I really like this splitting of the integral. I wish I could upvote twice!